# Audio script stopped working when I switched to div pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

Thanks for looking.

I am not a programmer and have just managed to cobble together a simple proof-of-principle "app" (using a bit of html, jquery and javascript) with a few pages, a bit of text, an image and an audio snippet.

However, I also needed to swipe from one page to another and was having problems making this work with separate html files. Finally I managed to get swiping working nicely (hurrah) by using 3  'pages' all in one index file but then the audio broke (boo) - note: it worked perfectly in separate html files.

I figured that there must be a problem with three identical audio scripts (one on each 'page') having the same function name, so I changed them to be unique. It still didn't work. I tried changing the *var* name too, No dice.

Can anyone suggest a tweak that would fix it? I am sure it's quite simple but I am stuck.

Here's my index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<title>HELLO</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-    1.2.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- set page swipes -->


<script>
<!--
$('div.ui-page').live("swipeleft", function(){
var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
if (nextpage.length > 0) {
$.mobile.changePage(nextpage, "slide", false, true);
}
});
$('div.ui-page').live("swiperight", function(){
var prevpage = $(this).prev('div[data-role="page"]');
if (prevpage.length > 0) {
$.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide",
reverse: true}, true, true);
}
});
// -->
</script>

</head> 

<body> 





<!-- Page 1 -->





<div data-role="page" id="home">

<div data-role="header"  data-theme="b">
    <h1>Bok!</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content" align="center">    


<img src="Aron_pic.png" width="170" height="170" alt="Lovely boy"></a><br>
<br><br>


<!--  audio script -->


<button onclick="playHi('hi.mp3')">Hi!</button>

<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script>
    function playHi(src) {
        if (device.platform == 'Android') {
            src = '/android_asset/www/' + src;
        }

        var media = new Media(src, success, error_error);

        media.play();
    }

    function success() {
        // ignore
    }

    function error_error(e) {
        alert('Error: check URL');
        alert(e.message);
    }
</script>

<!-- ???? -->




</div><!-- /end body content -->




</div><!-- /end page 1 -->








<!--  page 2 -->











<div data-role="page" id="goodbye">

<div data-role="header"  data-theme="b">
    <h1>Dovizenja!</h1>
</div>


<div data-role="content" align="center">    


<img src="Aron_pic.png" width="170" height="170" alt="Lovely boy"></a><br>
<br><br>



<!-- AUDIO FUNCTION -->
<button onclick="playBye('goodbye.mp3')">Goodbye!</button>

<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script>
    function playBye(src) {
        if (device.platform == 'Android') {
            src = '/android_asset/www/' + src;
        }

        var media = new Media(src, success, error_error);

        media.play();
    }

    function success() {
        // ignore
    }

    function error_error(e) {
        alert('Error: check URL');
        alert(e.message);
    }
    </script>

</div><!-- / end body content -->


</div><!-- /end page 2 -->






<!-- new page 3 -->







<div data-role="page" id="thankyou">

<div data-role="header"  data-theme="b">
    <h1>Hvala!</h1>
</div>


<div data-role="content" align="center">    


<img src="Aron_pic.png" width="170" height="170" alt="Lovely boy"></a><br>
<br><br>



<!-- AUDIO FUNCTION -->


<button onclick="playThanks('thankyou.mp3')">Thank you!</button>

<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script>
    function playThanks(src) {
        if (device.platform == 'Android') {
            src = '/android_asset/www/' + src;
        }

        var media = new Media(src, success, error_error);

        media.play();
    }

    function success() {
        // ignore
    }

    function error_error(e) {
        alert('Error: check URL');
        alert(e.message);
    }
    </script>

</div><!-- / end body content -->



</div><!-- /end page 3 -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any error in the browser console?

Comment: I am getting no error. I have been wrapping it in Phonegap Build and putting it on my Android phone. It just makes no sound

Comment: Did you try to launch the page directly without phonegap?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what that means. I dropped it in my browser, but the code for the audio never works from there anyway, only on the device

Comment: The point is, the audio was fine in separate pages, but in one long index page with div pages it isn't

Comment: It seems your source path is incorrect. You may want to use paths relative to your HTML

Comment: try to add the phonegap script at last one time and all the function into single, also when you swipe you have to destroy the media element

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal. Thanks, but I don't see why the path is incorrect now. It was fine in the separate HTML files and nothing has changed.

Comment: @DineshKumarDJ - thanks but I didn't quite understand. Can you be more explicit with the comments? I.e. what should I do with the Phonegap script exactly? How do I destroy the media element? I am not a programmer so could use some clear pointers/code. Thanks again

Comment: $('div.ui-page').live("swipeleft", function(){
var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
var currentPage = nextpage.attr('id');
if(typeof media[currentPage] !== "undefined"){
   media[currentPage].pause();
}
if (nextpage.length > 0) {
$.mobile.changePage(nextpage, "slide", false, true);
}
});

Comment: $('div.ui-page').live("swiperight", function(){
var prevpage = $(this).prev('div[data-role="page"]');
var currentPage = prevpage.attr('id');
if(typeof media[currentPage] !== "undefined"){
   media[currentPage].pause();
}
if (prevpage.length > 0) {
$.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide",
reverse: true}, true, true);
}
});

Comment: <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script>
var media = {};
    function playAudio(src) {

        if (device.platform == 'Android') {
            src = '/android_asset/www/' + src;
        }
 var currentPage = $.mobile.activePage[0].id;
 if(typeof media[currentPage] === "undefined"){
    media[currentPage] = new Media(src, success, error_error);
 }     
        media[currentPage].play();
    }

    function success() {
        // ignore
    }

    function error_error(e) {
        alert('Error: check URL');
        alert(e.message);
    }
</script>

Comment: last comment is the combined function of all

Comment: Many thanks Dinesh. I really appreciate your help on this. In fact I just got it working with the help of my brother who rewrote the audio script so that it was stated only once at the start and then applied in each instance of an audio button. PROBLEM RESOLVED

Comment: @DineshKumarDJ: Please POST your code as answer so that atleast the user can upvote if that serves his purpose